# Sigkill terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, tmux

I use tmux. Sometimes I have a terminal emulator open and I'd like to kill it without closing all my tmux windows. Right now I can do it with a `ps -u <user> | grep urxvt` followed by `kill <pid>`, but that doesn't  seem like a very nice way to do things.

What's the correct method to kill a terminal emulator (from the command line) without closing out tmux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know the exact name of the process, why dont you try to `killall <NameOfProc>`

```
$ killall urxvt
```

or

```
$ killal -u <user> urxvt
```

Comment: Works fine, but doesn't seem the nicest way to go about things -- is this really the 'good citizen' way to do it?

Comment: @Nate yes it is. in Linux kernel signaling is happening in the background every time you try 'close' a process.by default `killall` sends `SIGTERM` to the process a more forceful signals can be sent( using -s argument) if process didn't responds, like `SIGQUIT` and `SIGKILL`.the concept of signals also exist in windows under the name of 'messages'.